# Shared devise session in custom strategies

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, single-sign-on

I have two Rails applications, let's call them MainApp and ToolApp. They both use Devise: the MainApp uses standard `:database_authenticable`. The ToolApp uses a custom device strategy that uses MainApp API: ToolApp sends login and password and MainApp responds on success with  id, email and group name (these three values are stored in the ToolApp's session).

Now I'd like to share session between those two apps to provide single sign-on functionality. I set the same `Observer::Application.config.session_store` and `Observer::Application.config.secret_token`. Unfortunately session is still not shared -- when I log in to ToolApp, I'm not logged in to MainApp.

What's more I could do to share those sessions?

Comment: Just a long shot: but do you use database storage for sessions? Because it might be that if you use file storage, the file paths are different / relative to the app. Anyway, I'd use a OAuth strategy or if that is too much work, use :token_authenticatable

Comment: I use `:cookie_store` in both apps. Couldn't it be done by just sharing cookies?